# Google authentication using service account

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-client

GoogleCredential credential = new  GoogleCredential.Builder()
.setTransport(TRANSPORT)
.setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
.setServiceAccountId("SOMETHING@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
.setServiceAccountScopes(BigqueryScopes.BIGQUERY)
.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("key.p12"))
.build();

i tried above code to authenticate using service account. But
GoogleCredential is deprecated. So i am trying to use Credential.
But i am not able to understand what is mean by AccessMethod.
Can you please help me to refractor this code using Credential instead of GoogleCredential?

Comment: What language are you using? What library?

Comment: language - java  . Library is  google-api-client version 1.32.1. i am flexible in changing the library if there exists a compatible version. i just need the solution to authenticate using service account in Java

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, and as explained in [its JavaDoc reference](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-client/latest/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential.html), this class has been deprecated:

> **Deprecated.**
>
> Please use [google-auth-library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java) for handling Application Default Credentials and other non-OAuth2 based authentication.

Note that it already points you to another library: [google-auth-library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java). In that repository there is [an exaple of an impresionation](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java#impersonatedcredentials) by using it.